# checkbox is not unchecking on the change event of the jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

i have a checkbox and the button in my asp.net website,the button css property is set to hidden on the loading of the page,with the help of the checkbox i want to show and hide the asp.net button,the problem is that the check box is checked but i am not able to uncheck it....plz help i have give the code

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#Btnforgotpass").css('display', 'none');
        });


        $(document).ready(function () {


            $("[id$=chkforgotpass]").change(function () {

                if (document.getElementById("chkforgotpass").checked = true) {
                    alert('checked');
                    $("[id$=Btnforgotpass]").css('display', 'inline');

                }
                else {
                    alert('unchecked');
                    $("[id$=Btnforgotpass]").css('display', 'none');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: on your if statement try changing = to === you are assigning not comparing using this statement

Comment: thanx sir.....what a silly mistake from my side.....

Answer (score 0):

on your if statement try changing = to === you are assigning not comparing using this statement

```js
$(function() {
  $("#Btnforgotpass").css('display', 'none');
});


$(document).ready(function() {


  $("[id$=chkforgotpass]").change(function() {

    if (document.getElementById("chkforgotpass").checked === true) {
      alert('checked');
      $("[id$=Btnforgotpass]").css('display', 'inline');

    } else {
      alert('unchecked');
      $("[id$=Btnforgotpass]").css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="Btnforgotpass">
    Button
  </button>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkforgotpass">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change `if (document.getElementById("chkforgotpass").checked = true) {` to `if (document.getElementById("chkforgotpass").checked == true) {`

if you are using jQuery, it is too simple doing this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("[id$=chkforgotpass]").change(function() {
       var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked") : "inline" : "none";
       $("[id$=Btnforgotpass]").css('display', isChecked);
  });
});
```